# Vue директива, передавать разные значения

Tags: vue.js

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть директива, для работы с числами в INPUT, основная задача - это делить 1 000 000, ну и работа с дробями. Все чудесно работает, но есть одно но.

1000000 -> INT

"1 000 000" -> String

Как мне после изменения числа в INPUT отображать в INPUT непосредственно отформатированное число (с пробелами, запятыми и так далее ->>>> СЕЙЧАС ТАК И РАБОТАЕТ), но в модель (v-model) передать не отформатированное число, то есть убрать пробелы, и так далее.. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Конечно можно после каждой работы в самом компоненте парсить, убирать пробелы, и так далее, но данная директива будет использоваться достаточно много в проекте, поэтому, хотелось бы чтобы это работало в автоматическом режиме..

Comment: Покажите пример кода. Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под словом "директива"